Formatting JSON date string to WEEKDAY, MM/DD
I need to embed a JSON feed onto our website. I have my code working, but am struggling with the JSON date format, which is producing string values like 2024-05-08 18:00:00. Ideally, I would like to format this into something like Wednesday, May 8 6:00 PM or 05/08/2024 6:00 PM or along those lines. I am not able to edit the JSON feed directly.
My code is as follows:
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    fetch('jsonsource')
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            console.log(json);
            document.getElementById("feedtitle1").innerHTML = json[0].title;
            document.getElementById("feeddesc1").innerHTML = json[0].description;
            document.getElementById("feedurl1a").href = json[0].url;
            document.getElementById("feedurl1b").href = json[0].url;
            document.getElementById("feedurl1c").href = json[0].url;
            document.getElementById("feeddate1").innerHTML = json[0].start_date;
            document.getElementById("feedimage1").src = json[0].image;
        })
    });
</script>

<div class="FEEDcontainer">
    <div class="FEEDimg"><a href="" id="feedurl1a"><img src="" id="feedimage1" class="FEEDthumb"></a></div>
    <div class="FEEDtitle"><a href="" id="feedurl1b"><h1 id="feedtitle1"></h1></a></div>
    <div class="FEEDdesc"> <p id="feeddesc1"></p></div>
    <div class="FEEDmore"> <a href="" id="feedurl1c">Read more...</a></div>
    <div class="FEEDdate"> <p id="feeddate1"></p></div>
</div>

Do you have any tips?
I've tried getDate and moment, but they do not work with the date string my feed produces.

I would advise NOT to use ambiguous formats like mm/dd/yyyy or dd/mm/yyyy - what is the problem with this date format?

An additional function was what I needed
function formatJSONDate(jsonDate) {
var date = new Date(jsonDate);
var options = { weekday: 'long', month: 'long', day: 'numeric', hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', hour12: true };
var formattedDate = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options);
return formattedDate;
}

you may use
const dateString = json[0].start_date;
const d = new Date(dateString);
const time = d.toLocaleTimeString()
const date = d.toLocaleDateString()
console.log(date, time)

